# How to persist queue of AFHTTPRequestOperation in case of network error

Tags: iphone, ios, afnetworking

I need to continuously send data to a server. I'm using th AFNetworking lib.

In case that there is no or bad internet connection, I need to send this data again later if the connection is back.

These requests also need to be queued over app exits. So if the user opens the app again, the queue should be completed.

Is there a way to persist the AFHTTPRequestOperation to disk to use it later? Or do I have to store my request data separately and create new requests if the connection is back?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot persist queue. And you right - you have to store enough data for you to be able to retry at some point of time later.